# Building html documentation with SPHINX, FURO, AUTODOC. Error stylesheet

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

i try to use SPHINX with the FURO html-theme in my python project. As i try to build the html, the build fails.

I use following conf.py:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.


import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))


project = 'MyPorject+'
copyright = '2022, XXXXX' 
author = 'XXXX'
release = '0.3.0'


extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
              'sphinx.ext.duration']


autodoc_default_options = {'members': True,
                           'undoc-members': True,
                           'show-inheritance': True,
                           'recursive': True, }


templates_path = ['_templates']


exclude_patterns = []


html_theme = 'furo'


html_theme_options = {"light_css_variables": {"color-brand-primary": "#9e007e",
                                              "color-brand-content": "#00a9e0",
                                              },
                      "dark_css_variables": {"color-brand-primary": "#5c2483",
                                             "color-brand-content": "#2268b1",
                                             },
                      "light_logo": "logo-light-mode.png",
                      "dark_logo": "logo-dark-mode.png",
                      "announcement": "<em>Important</em> Doku befindet sich im Aufbau!",
                      }

html_static_path = ['_static']


pygments_style = "sphinx"
pygments_dark_style = "monokai"


napoleon_google_docstring = True
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
napoleon_include_init_with_doc = True
napoleon_include_private_with_doc = True
napoleon_include_special_with_doc = True`
```

As i tried to build with this conf.py this error has been printed:

```
Configuration error:
This documentation is not using `furo.css` as the stylesheet. If you have set `html_style` in your conf.py file, remove it.
```

But as you can see, there is no `html_style` set in my `conf.py`. I use Poetry to install into my `.venv`. I cant find any other use of `html_style` somewhere else in my Project. Can i set the stylesheet in my `conf.py`?
Do you have maybe a hint about my mistake... i guess it is something pretty obvious...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error with Sphinx 7.0.2 and Furo 2023.8.19. I updated sphinx to the latest version (7.2.5) as per this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pradyunsg/furo/issues/695) and that resolved it for me.

It looks like you need to run [`poetry update`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#update) for sphinx and furo.